# Getting arraylist from Service in BroadcastReceiver gives NullpointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a `AsyncTask` in a `Service`. I send an `ArrayList` as broadcast from the `AsyncTask`.

When I get the `ArrayList` in `onReceive()` I get a `NullpointerException`.

This is how I send the `ArrayList`.

```
 transits_list = new ArrayList<Transit>();
 transits_list.add(trs);

Intent arrayListIntent = new Intent("arrayList");
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putSerializable("transArray", transits_list);
intent.putExtra("extra", extra);
sendBroadcast(arrayListIntent);
```

The `Transit` class implements `Serializable`.

Receiving the `ArrayList`

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ArrayList<Transit> myList;

        Bundle extra = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extra");
        ArrayList<Transit> transArrayListFromBroadCast =     (ArrayList<Transit>) extra.getSerializable("transArray");
        System.out.print("transArrayListFromBroadCast "+transArrayListFromBroadCast);
    }
```

I get `NullpointerException` in this line:

```
ArrayList<Transit> transArrayListFromBroadCast =     (ArrayList<Transit>) extra.getSerializable("transArray");
```

The exception from log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=arrayList flg=0x10 } in com.prematix.tollsystem.avcc.AvccActivity$ArrayListReceiver@42003268
>                                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:798)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                              at com.prematix.tollsystem.avcc.AvccActivity$ArrayListReceiver.onReceive(AvccActivity.java:271)
>                                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:788)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

Answer (score 0):

Your method of getting the `Intent` is incorrect. I believe your `BroadcastReceiver` is in an activity class since, you are calling `getIntent()`. However, `getIntent()` will get you the `Intent` supplied to the activity and not the receiver. The `Intent` for `receiver` is provided to the method `onReceive()` itself. Make the following changes to your code:

Adding extra:

```
Intent arrayListIntent = new Intent("arrayList");
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putSerializable("transArray", transits_list);
intent.putExtra("extra", extra);
sendBroadcast(arrayListIntent);
```

Getting Extra:

```
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<Transit> myList;

    Bundle extra = intent.getBundleExtra("extra");
    ArrayList<Transit> transArrayListFromBroadCast = (ArrayList<Transit>) extra.getSerializable("transArray");
    // System.out.print("transArrayListFromBroadCast "+transArrayListFromBroadCast);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know